# JQuery UI Autocomplete with .Net MVC: How to display the label when selected but save the value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have implemented Autocomplete and I'm having trouble with the label vs. value in the text box after the item is selected.  When I type in a zip code, I see the label in the dropdown:

[image]

but after I select one, instead of the label showing in the text box, the value (which is the ID that needs to be saved to the database) is displayed:

[image]

How do I still show the label after it's selected, but then when the form is saved, it passes  the ZipCodeID for the field?

Here's my Controller method:

```
public JsonResult FindZipCode(string term)
    {
        VetClinicDataContext db = new VetClinicDataContext();

        var zipCodes = from c in db.ZipCodes
                       where c.ZipCodeNum.ToString().StartsWith(term)
                       select new { value = c.ZipCodeID, label = c.ZipCodeNum};

        return this.Json(zipCodes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And here's my markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ZipCodeID").autocomplete({
                  source: '<%= Url.Action("FindZipCode", "Customers") %>',
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="ui-widget"><input type="text" name="ZipCodeID" id="ZipCodeID" /></div>
```

EDIT:  Here's my final working code:

Controller:

```
public JsonResult FindZipCode(string term)
    {
        VetClinicDataContext db = new VetClinicDataContext();

        var zipCodes = from c in db.ZipCodes
                       where c.ZipCodeNum.ToString().StartsWith(term)
                       select new { value = c.ZipCodeID, label = c.ZipCodeNum};

        return this.Json(zipCodes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ddZipCode").autocomplete({
            source: '<%= Url.Action("FindZipCode", "Customers") %>',
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var zipCodeID = parseInt(ui.item.value, 1);
                $("#ddZipCode").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#ZipCodeID").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="ui-widget"><input type="text" name="ddZipCode" id="ddZipCode" /></div>
<%= Html.Hidden("ZipCodeID")%>
```

Comment: aren't zip codes unique enough to not need a seperate id? I can't fathom why you would want it otherwise

Comment: good point!  when I originally built the database I was quite new at it.  I set my zip codes up to have an auto incremented ID not really thinking that zip codes are unique themselves.  I could go back and change it now, but the effects would tricke into many other changes elsewhere.  I probably should do it anyway...  :) Thanks!

Comment: No problems. It's great that you're learning things and taking a pragmatic approach.

Comment: How do you send the search "term" in your method FindZipCode automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short of changing your model to not use a different ID for zip codes...

Create a hidden field for the zipcode id. Change the select behaviour to populate the hidden field with the ID and the visible one with the label.

See [The sample](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) for how to achieve this

Have you considered what happens if they type their own in?

Answer (score 4):

If you add the following lines it will display the label and NOT the id (which I would have thought should be the default, but hey).

```js
select: function (event, ui) {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.target.innerText = ui.item.label;
}
```

Comment: When I run this I get a runtime error in JavaScript: `Error: NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: DOM Exception 7` Any idea on how to get around this?